# cant get my @media code to fire, can you see why?

Tags: css, mobile, position, width, absolute

```
body .gilidPanel-opener {
top: 55%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px){
body .gilidPanel-opener {
  top: 85%;
}
}
```

i've been told in a previous question that i need to use 'absolute' on the element if i am using the value 'top'. absolute breaks the function of my element, does anyone know a way around this?

if you want to see for yourself, the page is www.focallocal.org and its the tab on the far left of the screen which i want to appear lower on a mobile device so it doesnt block reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called media query and it is fine. The reason it's not working is because your default css has higher priority than this. You are already using `fixed` position so `top` should work fine. Use this

```
@media all and (max-width: 700px){
  body .gilidPanel-opener {
    top: 85% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: that sounded highly sensible and likely, the free theme i'm using does require a lot of !important tags to override stuff. unfortunately it didn't work, no idea why.

Comment: Well, I edited on live website and it worked for me.

Comment: strange, the code is live now in my wordpress theme but something is preventing it from working.

Comment: oh, hang on. i set it to 5000 and it worked. it must just be the value i'm setting is not correct for mobile devices. my mistake, sorry and thanks very much for your help! i'll play around with values and try to get it working on a mobile.

Comment: i changed it to max-device-width and that along with the !important tag solved it. also, my Oppo find 5 has a ridiculously high resolution screen!